# How to pass a variable to AutoMapper at runtime for on the fly calculation?

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-6

I am trying to use AutoMapper 6.3 to allow me to auto map my models into view-models.

First I registered my AutoMapper instance to my `IUnitContainer` like so

```
var mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<TaskViewModel, Task>();
});

container.RegisterInstance<IMapper>(mapper.CreateMapper()); 
container.RegisterType<IUserPassport, UserPassport>(); // This has nothing to do with AutoMapper but is needed to convert date time.
```

Now, in my controller, I want to pull a model from the database, then I want to map/cast it to my view-model.

I tried to do the following

```
var task = UnitOfWork.Tasks.Find(x => x.Id == 123)
                           .ProjectTo<TaskViewModel>()
                           .FirstOrDefault();
```

However, my view model need's to know current user's time zone in order to convert time from UTC to local time zone. Somehow, I need to be able to pass `Passport.User.TimeZone` to the ViewModel to be able to process datetime converson?

Here is how I am trying to project the viewModel

```
public class TaskController : Controller
{
    private IUserPassport Passport;
    public TaskController(IUserPassport passport)
    {
        Passport = passport;
    }

    public ActionResult Show(int? id)
    {
        if (!id.HasValue)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        // Some how Passport.User.TimeZone needs to be passed to the 
        // TaskViewModel to the time stamps are converted.
        var task = UnitOfWork.Tasks.Find(x => x.Id == id.Value)
                               .ProjectTo<TaskViewModel>()
                               .FirstOrDefault();

        return View(task);
    }

}
```

Comment: You could write a custom resolver to do this. See [custom resolver documentation](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/docs/Custom-value-resolvers.md)

Comment: @12seconds how would I pass the User.TimeZone info to the resolver?

Comment: Resolvers don't work with ProjectTo. See [this](http://automapperdocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html#parameterization).

Comment: Do you want to add a property of type Timezone (may be not mapped to database) in your model and set it with Passport.User.TimeZone, and add the same to your ViewModel too ? Automapper will map it.